# devise password update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

Devise after updating the password redirects to /secret, instead of to user_root_path... how can i fix this?

Answer (score 1):

...mmmh.... have you set your root?

```
#routes.rb
root :to => 'home' # or wherever you want...
```